# struts2 <s:textfield /> generating table after compilation

Tags: java, html, css, struts2, html-table

I am using Struts2 `<s:textfield />` tag in HTML . After I compile the page and run it on web. the code gets automatically converted in **Table** format. What should I do to avoid the table generation or any extra code generation.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Comment: Lacks the sufficient information in your question. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want like this, using your form tag with theme simple

```
<s:form action="xxx" name="frmXX" method="post" theme="simple">
```

or configure into your struts.xml likes this

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

Struts default theme is xhtml theme and it renders like html table format. See this [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/why-do-the-form-tags-put-table-tags-around-controls.html).